# I would like to open and read a text file at program launch, using Qt

Tags: c++, c, qt, user-interface, io

I would like to open a text file at program launch, using Qt. I would like the text to appear in the text field which is called textEdit.

It is a simple notepad program that I am changing into an app I want to do other special things.

How do I input a text file, say "text.txt" into my textEdit widget upon program launch? All of the text file.

Writing with C++.

Thanks.

Comment: Go for the Qt-beginners guides. As far as i remember there is a textEditor example included. Some Pointers: ``QFile`` ``QTextDocument::setPlaintext()``

Comment: What beginner guides are you referring to?

Comment: How about [this example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/gettingstartedqt.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <QFile>
#include <QTextStream>

QString fileName = "myFile.txt";
File* myFile = new QFile(fileName);
if (myFile->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)
{
    QTextStream *myFileStream = new QTextStream(myFile);
    while ( !(myFileStream->atEnd()) )
    {
        QString line = myFileStream->readLine();
        textEdit->append(line);
    }
}
```